# Kohana ErrorException [Fatal Error] : Class 'Model_Winners' not found

Tags: php, kohana

```
class Controller_Home extends Controller {
    public function action_index()
    {
        $model_winners = new Model_Winners;
```

Kohana throws following exception when I try to create object of model named winners from controller.

Model winners:

```
class Model_Winners extends Model
{
    public function get($offset=0, $limit = 10)
        {
```

The Environment -> Included files lists file APPPATH/classes/model/winners.php

I'm aware of the file name conventions and case-sensitive nature. Tried the same code in WAMP stack too, but same exception thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue solved

I set **`'errors' => FALSE`** in Kohana init method.

This will revert system to show standard PHP errors.

The error was in fact thrown by an exception on database connection, this error was not shown on the stack trace when the Kohana error handler was handling the errors. After resolving the issue, re enabled the error handler by setting 'errors' => TRUE

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Kohana 3.3 the [files need top start with upper case](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/conventions), so the file path would be:

`APPPATH/classes/Model/Winners.php`.